# I can't send full data through ajax script on php language. (code igniter)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' charset='<?=$page_charset?>'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#btn_login').click(function(){
            $.search_keyword();
        });
    });
```

here is the script

```
<form name='frm_search_keyword'>
<table style='width:250px;'>
    <tr>
        <td style='width:100px;'>
            Search 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="web_keyword" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="btn_login" name="btn_login" value="search!" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

here is the form

```
search_keyword:function(type)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/web_keyword',
        data: {'b_type':type},
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            if(result == 12001)
            {
                alert('please choose your interest.');
                location.href = '/account/interest';
            }else
                location.href = '/'+type+'/'+result;
        }
    });
}
```

It successfully sends 'web_keyword' to db query and get result.
but I can't get type data through ajax script.
Can you help me to 'type' data from the form table to ajax script?

Thank you.

Comment: when  you are calling methong seach_keywork() i guess you are missing type there? are you expecting "type". Where is type suppose to come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is the problem, but it is suspect:

```
 $('#btn_login').click(function(){
        $.search_keyword();
    });
```

Where is "type" supposed to come from? What is "type" referring to? Is "type" a value returned from your DB query? Or is it something selected by the user when they perform the search?

If type is something within your form element, then use Javascript or jQuery, or whatever, to "harvest" that value from the page, and then you will need to pass that data to the AJAX functionality.

```
$('#btn_login').click(function(){
        //First get the "type" value, for example if "type" is retrieved from the form element
        var type = $('#btn_login').attr('type'); //this is for example's sake, since you did not assign an id to this form element...
        search_keyword(type);
    });
```

You just need to get "type" from where ever it is being generated and/or stored and pass it to your AJAX function.

Also, maybe this is irrelevant, but your "search_keyword()" function definition looks odd to me...

Instead of:

```
search_keyword:function(type){...}
```

Should be:

```
search_keyword = function(type){...}
```

One final thing, could you tell us which Javascript library you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
" dataType: 'json'," like 


   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/web_keyword',
   dataType: 'json',
        data: {'b_type':type},
    });
```

and return the date using

```
$data['return1']='true';
echo json_encode($data);


         success: function(result){
            if(result.return1 == 12001)
            {
                alert('please choose your interest.');
                location.href = '/account/interest';
            }else
                location.href = '/'+type+'/'+result;
        }
```

you should remove async:false

Setting this option to false is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive.